# Understanding effective potential energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, potential-energy

I am having troubles understanding whether $$\vec F=-\nabla U_{effective}$$ or $\vec F=-\nabla U$ with $$U_{eff}=U(r)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{L^2}{\mu r^2}$$ being $\mu=\frac{m_1 m_2}{m_1+m_2}$ the "reduced mass" of a 2-body-problem. My teacher says it is the $\vec F=-\nabla U(r)$ the one that is the integral of the force but then *my notes have to be wrong since I have written this whole thing from conservation of energy*:
$$E=T+U=\frac 12 \mu v^2+U(r)=\frac12 \mu \dot{r}^2+\frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2}+U(r)=cte$$ differentiating both sides wrt $r$ $$\mu \dot{r}+\frac{d}{dr}(\frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2})=-\frac{dU}{dr}$$ $$\mu \dot{r}=-\frac{d}{dr}(U+\frac{L^2}{\mu r^2})=\frac{d}{dr}U_{ef}=^?F(r)$$ so this suggests $\vec F=-\nabla U_{effective}$ and not $\vec F=-\nabla U$, what is wrong in my notes or what am I understanding wrongly?

Comment: *"...differentiating both sides..."* Differentiating both sides with respect to what?

Comment: @hft with respect to r... I thought it was obvious my bad I guess. But is it enough to dislike my question? Like what is even is wrong with my question? And how on earth is this a homework question?

Comment: @Ivy Note that the reason given for closure was that your question was *either* homework-like *or check-my-work* like, and your question is closer to the latter. I personally would tend to agree that the question should not have been closed. However, you did make a mistake (alluded to by user hft), which is that you differentiated some things with respect to $t$ and others with respect to $r$, and fixing that mistake may well answer your question.

Comment: Ivy, I also think the closure is a bit harsh. In Goldstein Poole and Safko, Chapter 3, the authors use the word "fictitious" rather than "effective" but I would say it is the same thing. At any rate the effective / fictitious force is equal to the r derivative of the effective / fictitious potential energy, where the actual force is the r derivative of the actual potential energy. So you should have "effectives" for both U and F. Note that some of the actual force is "used up" by CF, so your term is in fact the "effective force" seen as the second derivative of r.

Comment: Hi Ivy. You are including the fictitious centrifugal force in your calculation of the force, while your teacher is not. So you are both correct but you are using different definitions of the force.

Comment: @JohnRennie what do you mean? Could expand a little bit?

Comment: @J.Murray I edited the question, my bad, but then I only get to $\mu \dot{r}=\frac{dU_{ef}}{r}$ so there is no force that equals the derivative of a theorical potential energy?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/790141/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic wow that must've been my classmate, we are all the class very confused

Comment: *"differentiating both sides wrt r"* No. That is definitely not what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a conservative system with potential energy function $U(\mathbf r)$, the force on the system is given by $\mathbf F(\mathbf r) = -\nabla U(\mathbf r)$. This is essentially the *definition* of $U$. From this, you can construct the total energy
$$E(t) = \frac{1}{2} m |\dot{\mathbf r}(t)|^2 + U\big(\mathbf r(t)\big)$$
Differentiating with respect to time,
$$\dot E(t) = m \dot{\mathbf r}(t) \cdot \ddot{\mathbf r}(t) + \nabla U\big(\mathbf r(t)\big) \cdot \dot{\mathbf r}(t) = \dot{\mathbf r}(t) \cdot \underbrace{\left[m \ddot{\mathbf r}(t) + \nabla U\big(\mathbf r(t)\big)\right]}_{=0} = 0$$
which vanishes by Newton's 2nd law.

---

Notice, however, that $\mathbf F$ and $\mathbf r$ are *vectors*. We can decompose this expression into their components in the orthonormal polar basis $(\hat r, \hat \theta)$. If we do this, we find that
$$|\dot{\mathbf r}(t)|^2 = \dot r(t)^2 + r(t)^2 \dot \theta(t)^2$$

where $r(t) \equiv |\mathbf r(t)|$ is the radial coordinate.  Therefore, the expression for the energy becomes
$$E(t) = \frac{1}{2} m \dot r(t)^2 + \frac{1}{2} m r(t)^2 \dot \theta(t)^2 + U\big(r(t)\big)$$
where we have used the fact that $U$ does not depend on $\theta$ in this case. We could compute the time derivative of this expression, but the result would involve both $r$ and $\theta$ (and their derivatives). To simplify matters, we can use the conservation of angular momentum, which tells us that $L = m r(t)^2 \dot \theta(t)$ is constant. Using this, we can rewrite the energy expression as
$$E(t) = \frac{1}{2} m \dot r(t)^2 + \frac{L^2}{2mr(t)^2} + U(r)$$

Now the problem involves only $r$, and it is "effectively" one-dimensional. Differentating the above,
$$\dot E(t) = m \dot r(t) \ddot r(t) - \frac{L^2}{mr(t)^3} \dot r(t) + U'\big(r(t)\big) \dot r(t) = \dot r(t) \left[m \ddot r(t) - \frac{L^2}{mr(t)^3} + U'\big(r(t)\big)\right] = 0$$

which tells us that

$$m \ddot r(t) = - U'\big(r(t)\big) - \frac{L^2}{mr(t)^3}$$

Observe that if we define $U_{eff} (r) = U(r) + \frac{L^2}{2mr^2}$, the right-hand side becomes simply $-U'_{eff}\big(r(t)\big)$.

---

The takeaway from this is that $\mathbf F(\mathbf r) = - \nabla U(\mathbf r)$ is always true for conservative systems, where $\mathbf F$ is the *vector* force on the system. However, you can reduce the 2D problem (which involves $r$ and $\theta$) to a 1D problem (which involves only $r$) by defining the effective potential $U_{eff}(r) = U(r) + L^2/2mr^2$, in which case you have that $m\ddot r(t) = -U'_{eff}\big(r(t)\big)$.

---

To provide some additional clarity, notice that the rate of change of the radial velocity $\dot r \equiv \dot{\mathbf r} \cdot \hat r$ is **not** given by the radial component of the force:

$$m\frac{d}{dt} \dot r = \underbrace{m\ddot{\mathbf r}}_{\mathbf F} \cdot \hat r + m\dot{\mathbf r} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{d\hat r}{dt}}_{=\dot \theta \hat \theta} = F_r + mr \dot{\theta}^2$$

The first term on the right is equal to the radial component of the force, and is therefore equal to the radial component of the gradient of the potential:
$$F_r \equiv \mathbf F \cdot \hat r = -\nabla U \cdot \hat r = -U'(r)$$
where we again use that, in this case, $U$ is a function of $r$ but not $\theta$. The second component arises because we are working in curvilinear coordinates, where the unit vectors are not spatially constant. The extra term which appears is usually referred to as a  *centrifugal force* term - though of course, it is not a force at all.

Because angular momentum is conserved in this system, we may write $\dot \theta = L/mr^2$ with $L$ constant. Plugging that in yields
$$m\ddot r = -U'(r) + \frac{L^2}{mr^3} = -\frac{d}{dr} \left(U(r) + \frac{L^2}{2mr^2}\right)$$

where the centrifugal term $L^2/2mr^2$ acts like an effective addition to the potential energy. Defining $U_{eff}(r) = U(r) + L^2/2mr^2$, we may write
$$m\ddot r = - U'_{eff}(r)$$
and then forget about the $\theta$ coordinate until we've found the solution for $r$.

Comment: The thing is that I've seen some problems that given a central force like $F(r)=-kr^{5/2}$ applied to a mass $m$, the solution does $U_{efective}=\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}+U(r)=\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}-\int F(r)dr\neq \int F(r)dr$ since this is a 1D problem, isn't it? And therefore shouldn't it be $U_{ef}(r)=\int F(r)dr$? That's what I'm not understanding, I do understand what you said about the dimensions but in problems like that one I can't see why it shouldn't be the effective potential the one that is the derivative of the force

Comment: @Ivy I've added a section to the end of my answer. The extra term in $U_{eff}$ is not a component of the force - it is a centrifugal term which arises because we're working in curvilinear coordinates.